Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com
I am unable to update or install any packages through sudo apt-get
Following works:
`ping google.com`
`wget google.com`

However apt-get commands fail with an error like:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mesa-demos/mesa-utils_8.4.0-1build1_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out
However, I have already tried common solutions like:
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
But this also doesn't works.
Note: I am behind a proxy, with following environment variables sourced:
`export HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.xxx.ac.in:3128"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.xxx.ac.in:3128"
export https_proxy="http://proxy.xxx.ac.in:3128"
export http_proxy="http://proxy.xxx.ac.in:3128"`
Please suggest how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

You probably need to update (or create)
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
with
Acquire {
  HTTP::proxy "http://proxy_server:port/";
  HTTPS::proxy "http://proxy_server:port/";
}

This is according to https://linuxiac.com/how-to-use-apt-with-proxy/
